# How can mapped result from SQL native query to java POJO class (no entity)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have simple java pojo and it's no entity.

```
class MyClass {
    // fields, getter, setter and etc...
}
```

Also I have DAO with some function for execute native SQL query (createNativeQuery)

How can mapped result from SQL native query to MyClass without @Entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bean field names are the same as the DB table's column names, you can use Spring JDBC's `org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper<T>`.

You call `org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcOperations.queryForObject(String, RowMapper<T>, Object...)`) with the BeanPropertyRowMapper object and it calls all the setters for you, using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

If its JPA, I'd used:
Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sql.toString(), MyClass.class);

It works if MyClass is an EntityBean :-(

Comment: Unless MyClass.class is annoted with @Entity it will not work

Answer (score 0):

You can simply issue a query and call the getters/setters in your POJO class.
Pseudo-code:

```
get connection
ResultSet rs = execute query
if (rs.next()) {
  setField1(rs.getString("field1"));
  etc....
}
```

Comment: If you can't make it an entity I think this is your only route. Without bringing in another framework as proposed in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EclipseLink query redirector. The following link explains it. The author has also provided code which is pretty generic and works quite well.

http://onpersistence.blogspot.in/2010/07/eclipselink-jpa-native-constructor.html